# Convert time_point to string using std::format with format that includes date, time and subseconds

Tags: c++, format, c++20, c++-chrono

Let's assume we have a simple function that takes a std::chrono::time_point and returns a string using a given formatting string. Like so:

```
std::string DateTimeToString(std::chrono::sys_time, const char * szFormat /*= "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"*/)
```

According to the cppreference documentation of [std::formatter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/formatter) we should be able to use the individual tags to create a string like `2021/03/24 15:36:32.123123`. However, when the duration of the time_point uses microseconds (which is mandatory for our use) then this throws a format_error.

If we split this into to separate calls so that we use format for the date and time separately then it works. Like this:

```
auto tSysTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::string sTime = std::format("{:%H:%M:%S}", tSysTime.time_since_epoch());
std::string sDate = std::format("{:%Y/%m/%d}", std::chrono::sys_days(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::days>(tSysTime.time_since_epoch())));
```

Am I missunderstanding something or is there no way to have a single format string for my purpose? Keep in mind that the format string is an optional parameter so I cannot hardcode a split of individual parameters.

My expection would be to write

```
std::format("{:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}",tSysTime.time_since_epoch());
```

However, this crashes...

Thank you in advance for any help!

Edit: I'm using /std::c++latest flag in Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I'm not expert, but looks like implementation issue. You didn't wrote on which compiler you have this issue. Can you check alternative compilers?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that crucial info... I've updated the question, but it's the c++latest flag with Visual Studio 2019. I have no other compiler currently installed but will take a look!

Comment: @sklott At the moment it seems only MSVC have `std::format` implemented. So it's not really possible to check other compilers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need:

```
std::format("{:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}",tSysTime);
```

Or you can simplify it to:

```
std::format("{:%Y/%m/%d %T}",tSysTime);
```

If your `system_clock::time_point::duration` isn't `microseconds`, you can force it to microseconds precision with:

```
std::format("{:%Y/%m/%d %T}",floor<microseconds>(tSysTime));
```

The reason `std::format("{:%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S}",tSysTime.time_since_epoch());` fails is that the `.time_since_epoch()` turns the `time_point` into a `duration`.  And `duration`s know nothing about dates.  For example if you asked me what the current date and time is and I told you 1,616,600,192,123,123µs, you would look at me funny.  A `duration` knows nothing about an epoch.  A `duration` is just a measure of time between two `time_point`s.

A `time_point` on the other hand, knows about an epoch.  It holds a `duration` and means:  This much time `duration` beyond (or before) my epoch.

`std::format` understands the distinction between `time_point` and `duration`.  And so if the format string asks for dates (e.g. `%Y/%m/%d`) and you are formatting a `duration`, it throws an exception indicating insufficient information to do the requested job.  But if you give it a `time_point`, then `std::format` knows how to get the date information out of that.

This is all part of the type-safety design that `<chrono>` is built on, so that one can catch as many logic errors as possible, as early as possible.

```
int64_t i = 1'616'600'192'123'123;
microseconds d{i};
sys_time<microseconds> t{d};
cout << "i = " << i << '\n';
cout << "d = " << d << '\n';
cout << "t = " << t << '\n';
```

`i`, `d` and `t` all hold the same value in memory:  1,616,600,192,123,123, but mean different things.  And you can see these different meanings when you print them out:

```
i = 1616600192123123
d = 1616600192123123µs
t = 2021-03-24 15:36:32.123123
```

This is no different than:

```
char x = 'A';
int y{x};
cout << "x = " << x << '\n';  // x = A
cout << "y = " << y << '\n';  // y = 65
```

Comment: OMG of course THAT was the issue! I've spent so much time the last few days with chrono that the simple things like duration != time_point go completely over my head when dealing with issues... THANK YOU!

Comment: this doesnt work on Centos9 with g++ 11.2.1 .. not sure where you guys get these magic compilers.. `error: ‘format’ is not a member of std`

Comment: You can use my free, open-source, header-only, C++20 chrono preview: date.h:  https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Answer (score 0):

Helped me too. Thanks a lot.

```
const auto fileTime = dir_entry.last_write_time();
const auto systemTime = std::chrono::clock_cast<std::chrono::system_clock>(fileTime);
sort_string = std::format("{:%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S}", systemTime);
```